# function definition inside another function definition -slow?

Tags: python, performance, function, closures, decorator

Look at two ways of structuring my functions:

```
class myClass:
    def _myFunc(self):
        pass

    def myFunc2(self):
        self._myFunc()

class myClass:
    def myFunc2(self):
        def myFunc():
            pass

        myFunc()
```

Will the second option be slower?
I only need to call myFunc from myFunc2, so 'd like to hide it from my module documentation, I could use an underscore for that, but I thought it would be cleaner to have it inside the function. On the other hand I might need to call myFunc2 few hundred times per second, so "redefining" myFunc when calling myFunc2 each time might be slow... is that a good guess?

Comment: The only difference I can think of is something to do with global variables, and since the whole thing is wrapped in a class that's not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local function in the second variant won't be compiled over and over again -- it is compiled once together with the whole file, and its body is stored in a code object.  The only thing that happens during the execution of the outer function is that the code object is wrapped in a new function object which is then bound to the local name `myFunc`.

There might be a difference between the two variants if `myFunc()` takes default parameters.  Their definition would be executed over and over again in the second variant, resulting in a possible performance hit.

Exaggerated example:

```
from time import sleep

class MyClass:
    def _my_func(self, x=sleep(1)):
        pass
    def my_func2(self):
        self._my_func()

class MyClass2:
    def my_func2(self):
        def my_func(x=sleep(1)):
            pass
        my_func()
```

With the daft code above, `myClass.myFunc2()` will return immediately, while `myClass2.myFunc2()` takes a second to execute.

Comment: I don't quite understand why `myClass2.myFunc2()` takes a second, but `myClass.myFunc2()` returns immediately. Why the definition will be executed over and over agian in the second variant, if `myFunc()` takes default parameters?

Comment: @Alcott: The default argument is evaluated at the time the function definition is executed.  The second variant executes the function definition time and again because it's inside `my_func2()`.  The first variant executes the function definition only once.

Comment: Then I think, `myClass.myFunc2()` should take 1 sec to execute, and `myClass2.myFunc2()` should take 2 sec?

Answer (score 8):

Using Python 2.6.5 on 64-bit Ubuntu, there is no discernible difference:

```
# version 1
In [2]: %timeit c1.myFunc2()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 461 ns per loop

# version 2
In [3]: %timeit c2.myFunc2()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 464 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Dotted lookup (a.k.a. attribute binding) always takes longer than nested scope lookups.  The former involves a series dictionary of lookups and creation of a new object (a bound or unbound method).  The latter uses cell variables and are implemented using an array lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the other answers that claim there is no effect, I thought I should check.
I found a very definite advantage to defining the function outside.

```py
import random
def ff1(i):
    r1 = random.random()
    r2 = random.random()
    if r1 < 0.5:
        return i*r2
    else:
        return i/r2

def f1(i):
    return ff1(i)

def f2(i):
    def ff2(i):
        r1 = random.random()
        r2 = random.random()
        if r1 < 0.5:
            return i*r2
        else:
            return i/r2
    return ff2(i)
```

```py
%%timeit -r 10 -n 10 
x = 0.5
for i in xrange(10000):
    x = f1(x)
```

10 loops, best of 10: 4.2 ms per loop

```py
%%timeit -r 10 -n 10
x = 0.5
for i in xrange(10000):
    x = f2(x)
```

10 loops, best of 10: 5.33 ms per loop

```py
%%timeit -r 1 -n 1 
x = 0.5
for i in xrange(1000000):
    x = f1(x)
```

1 loops, best of 1: 438 ms per loop

```py
%%timeit -r 1 -n 1
x = 0.5
for i in xrange(1000000):
    x = f2(x)
```

1 loops, best of 1: 574 ms per loop